# UDEV rules of two cameras with same informations

Tags: shared-libraries, rules, udev

I have two devices with two different functionalities, but they have the same hardware information, how do I distinguish them when creating the UDEV rule in the operating system?

I use this commands for investigate more informations about hardwares:

Example: sudo udevadm info -ap /sys/class/input/input3
Example: sudo udevadm info -ap /dev/video0